# Powershell Error handling CSOM

Tags: powershell

I am currently writing some scripts in powershell client side and I haven't got much error handling. Can anyone give me any advice I have a few try and catches but that's about it. 
I noticed `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err` when would this be used?

Comment: This isn't really a SharePoint question, per say, so you might have better luck if it were to get moved to StackOverflow. But I would really suggest you add some code so that people could make some suggestions in context for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ErrorAction allows you to specify a custom error action for each cmdlet or each line of code in your script. In the code seen here, the first line of code informs you of an error if it occurs while retrieving the content of the c:\fso\computers.txt file. If an error occurs, after informing you of the problem, the script continues to the next line. The erroraction for the second line of code is stop. The script will halt if the Get-Content cmdlet is unable to find foo. This is shown here:

```
Get-Content -ErrorAction continue -Path C:\fso\Computers.txt
Get-Content -ErrorAction stop -Path foo
```

When the script runs, the output appears that is shown in the following image.
[image]

Allowed enumeration values: SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, and Inquire.

**SilentlyContinue:** The Windows PowerShell runtime will continue processing without notifying the user that an action has occurred.

**Stop:** The Windows PowerShell runtime will stop processing when an action occurs.

**Continue:** The Windows PowerShell runtime will continue processing and notify the user that an action has occurred.

**Inquire:** The Windows PowerShell runtime will stop processing and ask the user how it should proceed.